# Object.assign in one case create deep copy but in another only shallow

Tags: javascript

So, I know that `Object.assign` makes only a shallow copy of the object. BUT why then in the second `console.log()` it gives me a full deep copy merged with the new object?

I cnnot understand...

```js
const initialState1 = {
  boot: {
    items: [],
    pos: {},
    crType: [
      {
        additionalInfo: {
          blankCDs: 90
        },
        requirements: {
          items: [
            {
              count: 0
            },
            {}
          ]
        }
      },
      {},
      {}
    ],
    toggleDispatch: () => {},
    showSelector: false,
  }
}

const showPopup = {
  boot: {
    showSelector: true
  }
}

console.log(Object.assign(initialState1, showPopup))


const initialState2 = {
  callback: () => {},
  itemId: 0,
  lastSubID: 0,
  close: () => {},
  current: 0,
  state: '',
  isShopComplete: false,
  requirements: {
    minLevel: {
      available: false
    }
  }
}


 const educ = {
  requirements: {
    minLevel: {
      available: true
    }
  }
}


console.log(Object.assign(initialState2, educ))
```

Comment: It doesn't *truncate* the object depth. Merely the *copy* is shallow. Meaning, the nested objects have not been copied and still reference the originals.

Comment: it does not help me to understand @deceze

Comment: Read this, your answer is [here.](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. It doesn't *merge* anything. It replaces the `requirements` property of the first object with the value from the second. It may appear "merged", but only because those two `requirements` are identical except for the `true`/`false` value. But it hasn't been merged, it's been replaced entirely.

Comment: @deceze `merged` or `replaced` - it's te same for me in this case. I mean, that in the second console.log my objects does not fully replace each other, but only replace props by dublicate `keys` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the top level properties in the latter object are assign to the same property in the former object. I.e.:

```
Object.assign({ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' })
```

This ends up as `{ foo: 'baz' }`, because the value of the key `foo` from the second object is assigned to the property `foo` of the first object.

```
{                   {
  foo: 'bar'  <---    foo: 'baz'
}                   }
```

And so it happens in your two objects as well:

```
{                                      {
  boot: {                   <----        boot: {
    items: [],              <----          showSelector: true
    pos: {},                <----        }
    crType: [...],                     }
    toggleDispatch: () => {},
    showSelector: false,
  }
}
```

Only one top-level property, `boot`, gets overwritten, but that's pretty much your entire object in this case.

```
{
  callback: () => {},
  itemId: 0,
  lastSubID: 0,
  close: () => {},
  current: 0,
  state: '',
  isShopComplete: false,           {
  requirements: {         <----      requirements: {
    minLevel: {           <----        minLevel: {
      available: false    <----          available: true
    }                     <----        }
  }                       <----      }
}                                  }
```

Only one top-level property gets overwritten, but there are more properties which do not have an equivalent peer in the second object, and they stay as is.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, it is creating a shallow copy. You need to understand that a shallow copy does not mean that the object depth is 1 but rather the key-value pairs contain the reference to the same object instead of copies.

That is, if you change an internal object's property, it is reflected in the original object. In the first case, if you change the `showSelector` attribute of the object returned by the `Object.assign` method, it will be reflected on `showPopup` object. This is what a shallow copy means.

In the second case too, if you change the `requirements.minLevel` attribute, it will reflect on `educ` object.

Comment: Did you run my code there? What did you see? In 1st case the `initialState` was been fully replaced by the second obbject. But in the 2nd case the `initialState` just "upgrade"(replace) only dublicated keys value. That is I cannot understand

Comment: @MaxTravis that's what `Object.assign()` does; that's the whole point. It copies properties from the source object to the destination object. It does not affect any properties from the destination object if the property names are not keys of the source object.

Comment: @MaxTravis in the first example, the destination object only has one property ("boot").